# Camera.open() and setPreviewDisplay() undefined for the type Camera

Tags: android, camera

I am receiving an error while trying to open a camera through `mCamera = Camera.open();` option. The error says: `The method open() undefined for the type Camera`

The same error also appears for the following methods:

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
mCamera.startPreview();
mCamera.stopPreview();
mCamera.lock();
mCamera.release();
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: so you have `Camera mCamera;` before this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check your imports. I had a similar problem and the Camera object Eclipse chose for me was:
`import android.graphics.Camera;` instead it should be: `import android.hardware.Camera;`